# Google App Engine Console shows more entities than I created

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-console-developer

I recently deployed my app on GAE.

In my Datastore page of Google Cloud Console, in the Dashboard Summary, it shows that I have 75 entities. However, when I click on the Entities tab, it shows I have 2 entities of one kind and 3 entities of another kind. I remember creating these entities. I'm just curious where the 75 entities comes from?

Just checking if I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: Can you see more about what those other entities are? Are they entities of your models or ?

Comment: Look at each entities kind. See what kind these extra entities represent. It's possible you will find them under _ah_SESSION kind.

Comment: In the dropdown menu, there are only 2 entities kind. These are my two models, one with 2 entities and the other with 3 entities. No info on any other kinds or where the other entities came from.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the little question-mark near the statistics summary it says the following:

> Statistics are generated every 24-48 hours. In addition to the kinds used for your entities, statistics also include system kinds, such as those related to metadata. System kinds are not visible in your kinds menu. Note that statistics may not be available for very large datasets.

Could be any of these.